# How do I search for posts by date in Facebook Groups?

Tags: search, facebook-groups

I'm trying to find the oldest post in a FB group.

Is there a way to do this short of scrolling down to the very first post?

It's rather impractical in my case, the group has thousands of post as of this writing.